# Looking for a solid analytics tool for my team

Tags: sql, analytics

My team currently uses Redash to create dashboards that display information of our product.
We have an ETL pipeline that loads all the relevant data from multiple DB's to a MySQL database.

We then have a few MySQL queries that read from that DB, filter data, make important tables etc into what Redash calls query results.

We then create many queries on those query results, join then with other queries (basically another pipeline of queries) and that ultimately what makes our dashboard.

The thing we like about Redash are:

- An SQL editor (A must).
- Using results from queries in other queries.
- It has an option to cache results of queries and then use those cached results, which is very
  helpful when writing complex queries with many joins and saves us a lot of time.
- It's free.

We want to move to a different platform mainly because the visualisations are terrible and too basic for our needs.

We tried Metabase but for some reason it sucks all the available CPU of the server hosting the DB (It does all of the processing on our DB unlike Redash which does all the processing on its internal DB).

Microsoft gave us an offer we couldn't **not** refuse for Power BI (too many digits in the price tag).

If you know other analytics tools I would love to hear about them and your experience with them.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Bold BI](http://www.boldbi.com) provides an end to end Business Intelligence Solution that is an option to consider.

[image: Bold BI]

- - An SQL editor (A must): Yes. Using [Code View](https://help.syncfusion.com/bold-bi/connecting-through-custom-sql-query)
- - Using results from queries in other queries.  : Yes. Code View mode option can support sub queries.
- - It has an option to cache results of queries and then use those cached results, which is very helpful when writing complex queries with many joins and saves us a lot of time: No. Caching is not available currently but is scheduled to be included by September/October 2020.
- - We want to move to a different platform mainly because the visualisations are terrible and too basic for our needs.  : You can see the available visualizations [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/bold-bi/enterprise-bi/visualize-data/configure-widgets/column-chart). [Custom visualizations](https://help.syncfusion.com/bold-bi/enterprise-bi/visualize-data/configure-widgets/custom-widget#creating-new-widget) can also be created.
- - Optimized CPU usage: Bold BI can work in extract mode and move the data from your database to its internal database.
    -* Pricing: [Embedded](https://www.boldbi.com/embedded/pricing), [Cloud](https://www.boldbi.com/cloud/pricing)

Note: I work for Syncfusion (Bold BI).